# How to fix SIGSEGV Segmentation fault error?

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, gdb, ubuntu-18.04

I am running [open source code](https://github.com/hongzimao/pensieve) from a research paper and encountered a segmentation fault error.

I used `gdb` to view the core file that was generated and used `bt full` to learn more about what went wrong, but I am very very new to c++, so I don't know how to use the information given to further debug this error.

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  __GI_____strtof_l_internal (nptr=0x0, endptr=0x7ffecd484cd8, group=<optimized out>, loc=0x7f32914c5560 <_nl_global_locale>)
    at strtod_l.c:609
609 strtod_l.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt full
#0  __GI_____strtof_l_internal (nptr=0x0, endptr=0x7ffecd484cd8, group=<optimized out>, loc=0x7f32914c5560 <_nl_global_locale>)
    at strtod_l.c:609
        negative = 0
        num = {0, 0, 0, 511101108348, 390842024046, 0, 0, 4, 18446744073709551504, 140732342488280}
        numsize = 0
        exponent = 0
        base = 10
        den = {140732342488280, 0, 4, 139855159296252, 139855168706208, 0, 14395410707824902144, 4, 140732342488288, 139855165608536}
        densize = <optimized out>
        retval = {206158430210}
        bits = 0
        cp = 0xffffffffffffffff <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffffff>
        tp = <optimized out>
        startp = <optimized out>
        start_of_digits = <optimized out>
        expp = <optimized out>
        dig_no = <optimized out>
        int_no = <optimized out>
        lead_zero = <optimized out>
        c = <optimized out>
        decimal = 0x7f329128e7d8 <dot> "."
        decimal_len = 1
        thousands = 0x0
        grouping = 0x0
        cnt = <optimized out>
        current = <optimized out>
        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = "____strtof_l_internal"
        lowc = <optimized out>
#1  0x0000562b2bf93133 in get_all_cooked_time_bw(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) ()
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x0000562b2bf8f2ab in main ()
No symbol table info available.
(gdb) quit
```

I'm guessing that this is where things went wrong: 
`cp = 0xffffffffffffffff <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffffff>`,
but I have no idea what `cp` stands for or where and how to fix this.

Here is the relevant code:

```
void split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.str(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}

ALL_COOKED_TIME_BW get_all_cooked_time_bw(std::string path) {
    ALL_COOKED_TIME_BW all_cooked_time_bw;
    struct dirent *entry;
    DIR *dir = opendir(path.c_str());
    if (dir != NULL) {
        while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
            if (entry->d_name[0] == '.') continue;  // read . or ..

            std::string file_name = "";
            file_name += COOKED_TRACE_FOLDER;
            file_name += entry->d_name;
            printf("%s\n", file_name.c_str());

            std::ifstream in_file(file_name);
            std::string line;
            std::vector<float> cooked_time;
            std::vector<float> cooked_bw;

            if (in_file.is_open())
            {

                while ( getline (in_file, line) )
                {
                    std::vector<std::string> parse = split(line, '\t');
                    cooked_time.push_back(std::stof(parse[0]));
                    cooked_bw.push_back(std::stof(parse[1]));
                }
                in_file.close();
            }

            all_cooked_time_bw.all_cooked_time.push_back(cooked_time);
            all_cooked_time_bw.all_cooked_bw.push_back(cooked_bw);
            all_cooked_time_bw.all_file_names.push_back(entry->d_name);

        }
    }
    closedir(dir);

    return all_cooked_time_bw;
}
```

Comment: It's a little bit hard to say what `cp` is from exposed data. It might be really the problem (if it's e.g. one of the arguments to be processed in `strtod_l.c`). It might be as well a variable which is just not yet initialized or assigned and hence harmless. To sort this out, you should "walk up" the stack and check how the data is looking which is passed in the resp. function calls.

Comment: And, btw. there could be as well something wrong in the `<optimized out>` variables (which are probably stored in registers at the time of crash).

Comment: Looking twice, I recognized the `__GI_____strtof_l_internal (nptr=0x0, endptr=0x7ffecd484cd8, group=<optimized out>, loc=0x7f32914c5560 <_nl_global_locale>)`. `nptr=0x0` looks somehow suspicious as well but without more info it's just a shot into the blue. So, my hint again: walk up the stack to check the arguments in function calls...

Comment: at a guess the string passed to `get_all_cooked_time_bw` is corrupt

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for your response. Could you maybe also explain why it says `strtod_l.c: No such file or directory.`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Could you elaborate on what corrupt means? Thank you

Comment: you don't have the source code of the c runtime available

Comment: corrupt means not valid in some way, without any source code its difficult to say more

Comment: In addition to Alan: `strtod_l` is (probably) one of the standard library functions which you may have installed as binary. Hence, you don't have source code (or gdb cannot find it). I don't expect that `stdtod_l()` is your problem but how it is called directly or indirectly...

Comment: Bottom line - you cannot fix this with what little information you are offering.

Comment: `get_all_cooked_time_bw` is passing  a null pointer to `strtof` (or some related conversion function).

Comment: At a guess [`split`](https://github.com/hongzimao/pensieve/blob/1120bb173958dc9bc9f2ebff1a8fe688b6f4e93c/test/dp.cc#L108) is returning less than 2 elements, this method needs some bounds checking

Comment: [`std::stof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) shouldn't be used without passing and checking the `pos` argument either

Answer (score 1):

If the line passed to `split` here doesn't contain 2 (or more) elements:

```
std::vector<std::string> parse = split(line, '\t');
```

Then the following 2 lines cause undefined behaviour by passing invalid strings to `std::stof`:

```
cooked_time.push_back(std::stof(parse[0]));
cooked_bw.push_back(std::stof(parse[1]));
```

This should be fixed with some more defensive programming:

```
if ( parse.size() != 2 )
{
   throw std::invalid_argument("invalid file: " + file_name);
}
cooked_time.push_back(std::stof(parse[0]));
cooked_bw.push_back(std::stof(parse[1]));
```

You should also in most cases pass a `pos` argument to `std::stof` as otherwise it ignores non-numeric characters at the end of the string. e.g.:

```
size_t pos;
cooked_time.push_back(std::stof(parse[0], &pos));
if (pos != parse[0].size())
{
   throw std::invalid_argument("invalid file: " + file_name);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, your input really helped a lot. This turned out to be a silly mistake, all I had to do was change '\t' to ' '.